# Private Docker registry with token authentication not able to list the images

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-registry

Hi I am having **private docker registry with token based auth** where I am able to do the following:

1. Authenticate & Login to my private registry from command line via **docker login**
   successfully.
2. Push images to private registry
3. Pull images from the private registry

I am facing issues when I try to achieve the following tasks:

1. List all the private registry images
2. Show details of specific docker image
3. Show tags of specific docker image

Docker Registry - registry.my-domain.com
NodeJs/ExpressJs APIs - testapi.api-domain.com

Following is my complete code for Docker Registry in **NodeJs / ExpressJs**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const libtrust = require("libtrust");
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const winston = require("winston");
const { compare } = require("../../helpers/bcrypt.helper.js");
const Route = express.Router();
const { Developer } = require("../../models/DeveloperModel.js");
const { findByEmail } = require("../../services/developer.service.js");
const { dockerLoginValidation } = require("../../validations/auth.validation.js");

//Docker registry token options
function createTokenOptions(request) {
    const options = {};

    options.headers = request.headers;

    options.account = request.query.account;
    options.service = request.query.service;
    /* Issuer value must match the value configured via docker-compose */
    options.issuer = "registry.my-domain.com";

    const parts = request.query.scope && request.query.scope.split(":");

    if (parts && parts.length > 0) {
        options.type = parts[0]; // repository
    }

    if (parts && parts.length > 1) {
        options.name = parts[1]; // foo/repoName
    }

    if (parts && parts.length > 2) {
        options.actions = parts[2].split(","); // requested actions
    }

    return options;
}

/** For time being I am give pull & push permission to everyone */
async function authorize(options) {
    const { account } = options;

    //Mongodb lookup Repository from Developer collection and check if the user has access to the repository
    const developer = await Developer.findOne({ email: account });

    /** If unauthorized access then only pull permissions is granted */
    return ["pull", "push"];
}

//Docker registry create token
function createToken(options, actions) {
    const { account, service, issuer, type, name } = options;

    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem", { encoding: "utf8" });

    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.my-domain.com/privkey.pem", { encoding: "utf8" });

    const keyId = libtrust.fingerprint(publicKey);

    const headers = {
        alg: "RS256",
        typ: "JWT",
        kid: keyId,
    };

    const claimSet = {
        iss: issuer,
        sub: account,
        aud: service,
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
        nbf: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 10,
        iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
        jti: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
        password: "admin",
        // jwtid: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
        access: [
            /* {
                type: type,
                name: name,
                actions: actions,
            }, */
            {
                type: type,
                name: "*",
                actions: ["pull", "push"],
            },
        ],
    };

    return jwt.sign(claimSet, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256", keyid: keyId, header: headers });
}

//TODO: Login attempts limit to x
Route.get("/login", async (request, response) => {
    // Extract the base64 encoded string from the authorization header
    const authorizationString = request.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    // Decode the base64 encoded string
    const credentialsString = Buffer.from(authorizationString, "base64").toString();
    // Split the decoded string by the colon (:) character to get the username and password
    const [username, password] = credentialsString.split(":");

    const errors = dockerLoginValidation({
        username: username,
        password: password,
    });

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            status: "error",
            message: "Invalid email or password.",
            errors: [
                {
                    message: "Invalid email or password",
                    field: "email",
                },
            ],
        });
    }

    const user = await findByEmail(username);

    if (!user) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            status: "error",
            message: "Invalid email or password.",
            errors: [
                {
                    message: "Invalid email or password",
                    field: "email",
                },
            ],
        });
    }

    if (!(await compare(password, user.password))) {
        return response.status(401).json({
            status: "error",
            message: "Invalid email or password.",
            errors: [
                {
                    message: "Invalid email or password",
                    field: "email",
                },
            ],
        });
    }

    const tokenOptions = createTokenOptions(request);

    const actions = await authorize(tokenOptions);
    const userJWTToken = createToken(tokenOptions, actions);

    await user.updateOne({
        $push: {
            tokens: {
                token: userJWTToken,
                expiration_at: new Date().setSeconds(process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_SECONDS),
            },
        },
    });

    return response.status(200).send({
        status: "success",
        message: "Authenticated user successfully.",
        token: userJWTToken,
    });
});

module.exports = Route;
```

The following is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry:2.8.1
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET: 134452-9a3f-4c73-bf5e-e0864b400bc8

      #S3 bucket as docker storage
      REGISTRY_STORAGE: s3
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY: BKIB2R7IHLTIV6GQIAUV
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY: 1qu05ApbfizVg0+KM9LvUPDU4STL9Ez1c1hneOXS
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION: us-east-1
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET: my-domain-docker-registry
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: false

      #Docker token based authentication
      REGISTRY_AUTH: token
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM: "https://testapi.my-domain.com/api/docker/auth/login"
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE: "Authentication"
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER: "registry.my-domain.com"

      #Letsencrupt certificate
      REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE: "/certs/live/registry.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem"
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: "/certs/live/registry.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem"
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: "/certs/live/registry.my-domain.com/privkey.pem"
      # REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_AUTOREDIRECT: false
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

    restart: always

    volumes:
      - "/etc/letsencrypt:/certs"
```

When I try to list the docker images I keep getting the following error even after passing the

**Authorization: Bearer TOKEN**

Following is the error in the Postman

[image]

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, even though I hardcoded the correct access needed to in the token.      const payload1 = {
      iss: "localhost:3000",
      sub: "nandha",
      aud: "localhost:6001",
      // exp: expirationTime,
      nbf: issuedAt,
      iat: issuedAt,
      jti: uuid(), 
      access: [
        {
        "type": "registry",
        "name": "catalog",
        "action": ["*"]
        }
      ]
    };